# Nestjs Interceptor how to catch http 401 error and resubmit original request

Tags: nestjs

I need to write an http header interceptor to add Authorization header, if there is a 401 error, submit another request for a new token, then resubmit the original request with the new token.

```
intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {

    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();

    return next.handle().pipe(

      catchError(async error => {

        if (error.response.status === 401) {

          const originalRequest = error.config;

          var authRes = await this.authenticationService.getAccessToken();
          
          this.authenticationService.accessTokenSubject.next(authRes.access_token);

          // I need to resubmit the original request with the new token from here
          // but return next.handle(originalRequest) doesn't work

        }
        return throwError(error);

      }),
                
    );
  }
```

But next.handle(originalRequest) doesn't work. How to resubmit the original request in the interceptor? Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: can you share the code of the intercept function

Comment: I edited the intercept function in the post

Comment: Sounds like a client job for me, or maybe handle this logic in your validation code that returns 401 in the first place?

Comment: I'd like to have the interceptor to deal with 401 error so that there is no need to write validation codes for every http requests. In Angular, it's pretty easy. I assume nestjs should be same

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered a similar problem, where I can catch the exception from exception filter but can't do so in interception layer.

So I looked up the [manual](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards#putting-it-all-together) and found it says:

```
Any exception thrown by a guard will be handled by the exceptions layer 
(global exceptions filter and any exceptions filters that are applied to the current context).
```

So, if the exception is thrown from AuthGuard context(including the validate method in your AuthService), probably better to move the additional logic by extending the Authguard
like this:

```js
export class CustomizedAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('strategy') {
    handleRequest(err, user, info, context, status) {
        if (err || !user) {
            // your logic here
            throw err || new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

or simply using customized exception filter.